# How to solve the javascript error while calling Azure AD B2C via OAuth Azure function?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

Getting this below error while calling Azure AD B2C via oAuth Azure function, it is throwing this error suddenly without any changes.

The call is made via Postman, this POST request is made by the client to get the access token with the B2C registered app's client_id & client_secret, also this is a grant_type=client_credentials flow

`<div class=\"error_container\"><div><h1>We can't sign you in</h1><p>Your browser is currently set to block JavaScript. You need to allow JavaScript to use this service.</p><p>To learn how to allow JavaScript or to find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, check the online help in your web browser.</p></div></div></div></noscript><div id=\"no_cookie\"  class=\"no_display\"><div class=\"error_container\"><div><h1>We can't sign you in</h1><p>Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.</p><p>Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.</p></div></div></div>`

Comment: What request? To where? Sounds like you called the /authorize endpoint, which returns this error when you call it from anything that isn’t a JavaScript enabled browser.

Comment: The call is made via Postman, this POST request is made by the client to get the access token with the B2C registered app's client_id & client_secret, also this is a grant_type=client_credentials flow

Comment: which endpoint you are hitting?  can you send that?

Comment: How do you use postman to request a token? For Azure b2c, it does not currently support client credential flow.

Answer (score 0):

Azure b2c does not yet support using client credential flow to obtain tokens, try to use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) to obtain tokens.

[image]